# Get the number of Pocket PC devices connected to my PC

Tags: c#, rapi

Hii...
I want to find out the number of Pocket PC devices(In my Case they are RFID reader's).Is there any way to do thi using RAPI in C#.net?can you please help me out....

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one device connected to your PC at any time. So you only need to check if a device is actually connected. See here for [example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249144). I also recommend to have a look at OpenNetCF RAPI.

Comment: R U Sure?I mean I want to have multiple readers connected to my PC & then one by one work on them.....

Comment: If you mean connected by means of ActiveSync or Windows Mobile Device Center, there can only be one device connected.

Answer (score 0):

Only one device (PocketPC) can be connected at a time via ActiveSynch.

Answer (score 0):

is it now possible to do this with RAPI2?

msdn says yes...but I don't get it working.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee497070.aspx:

> For Windows CE 5.0 and earlier, this
>   enumeration sequence will only contain
>   a single connected device.